# Estimation using nested data

Tags: mixed-model, hierarchical-bayesian, nested-data

I want to estimate the average income for a location. I have nested data in the following way: A block is inside a neighborhood, which is inside a zipcode, which is inside a district, which is inside a region, which is inside a state.

I want to estimate the average income at a block level, and the issue is that I don't have much data at that level. I have much more data at a state level, but it is not such a good approximation.

How would you deal with this problem? Are there any ways to incorporate the uncertainty of not having many data points at a block level? Are there any Bayesian frameworks that allow us to incorporate data of all levels? Can it be mixed models?

Comment: Can you give more details on the data structure, it sounds like you might not have only individual data, but also totals on some levels? sample sizes, ...

Comment: Yeah I only have individual data, but few of them at block level. Many blocks less than 5 individuals. Most of them have less than 10. There are like 5 blocks by neighborhood, 10 neighborhoods in a zipcode, 20 zipcodes inside a district, 10 districts inside a region, and 10 regions inside a state. These are roughly the data I have, let me know if it's clear.